# Should a library expose helper classes?

Tags: c#, dll

We're designing an internal-only library that will serve as a core business object model for several upcoming applications. It covers mostly Customers of various types and Documents of various types.

Obviously we want to ensure that if you're going to use these objects, and especially if you're going to serialize them, that they have valid, sane values.

So for instance, a Customer has contact info, and that includes a phone number. So there's an `ITelephoneNumber` interface, base class, a US implementation, all that. The library uses these classes to validate its data.

But really, a Customer is a more of a "core" business object for us, and a PhoneNumber less so; it feels a little weird writing a bunch of structure for phone numbers, and exposing that as Our-Library-Goodness. They seem 'out of scope' a bit.

Phone numbers are one example; there are other things. We could refactor these class structures to static methods but then we have lengthy constructors and they have to "just know" to use the methods, etc. We made the decision to go with classes for a lot of this.

### My question is

Should the library *consumers* have to work with these helper classes that aren't really necessary to *define* the core objects? As in:

```
MyCustomer.SetTelephoneNumber(new USTelephoneNumber("555", "555", "5555%$&"));
```

which give you compile-time feedback, their own members (AreaCode, Exchange...) and so on.

Or should we just leave the means of getting a valid phone number up to the implementation, and be more 'black box' about it? As in:

```
MyCustomer.SetTelephoneNumber("555-555-5555%$&");
```

which would just throw an error or silently fail/succeed or return a string.Empty or whatever.

---

I don't know if this question can be 'answered', and I don't want to start any holy wars. I'm looking for some reasoning either way. We're just a 2-man team trying to do the right thing in an agency that couldn't care less about code quality or maintainability.

Comment: To me both forms are valid and I would implement the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this issue is that you stated it is an "internal only library." This means it is entirely up to the internal development team to determine how the library is implemented. To make those decisions, I would look at the value of the two implementation possibilities.

Does the more complex implementation save you time and effort in later development?

Does the more complex implementation keep you from writing validation code over and over when you use the library?

Those are the questions that can help you determine if the complex implementation is valuable. If the coding up front is going to save you time in the long term, then it is worth it. If the coding up front isn't going to save time and effort in the foreseeable future, then it is not worth the effort.

Comment: You're saying the practical use we get from the library is more important than the potential or theoretical issues of it being 'polluted' with things that aren't strictly within the domain.

Answer (score 1):

This question probably can't be answered, as you note. So this is not an answer, but (since it's too long for a comment) I'll write it here:
I would go for both options, providing both overrides for `SetTelephoneNumber`

How does your Customer class know how to validate the phone number as a US number? If you are assuming that a US Customer will have a US phone number, that assumption may be wrong in some cases. So it's fair both to have a "simple" override that takes care of the most likely scenario and an override that allows you to specify uncommon cases.

Your system will also become easier to test, if you can inject different types of validation logic for phone numbers instead of having them "hidden" in the class.

That said, I would not overthink this too much. It's good to "try to do the right thing" but it's also easy to fall in the [FizzBuzz Enterprise Edition](https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition) syndrome.

Answer (score 1):

Phone numbers seem to be part of your domain, so expose them. Ideally, all your code in the entire app would share this phone number object and standardize on it. Maybe it should even exist at a lower layer (a data formats library or so, that is independent of higher-level objects like customers).

Comment: Email addresses and postal addresses and a dozen other non-contact-related things are also 'part of the domain'. You're saying that whatever we decide is a 'valid' form of the data, we ought to also provide our means of validating it?

Comment: I don't see whats wrong with exposing standardized formats for phone numbers and such. The domain encompassed both entities (customer, order, ...) as well as value object (address, phone number, ...). You can cleanly expose anything that is part of the domain *and* has meaning to the caller. "Micro-formats" seem to have meaning to the caller.